# Classifying critical points (general)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

> Consider the system  $$ \begin{bmatrix}  x_1 \\ x_2  \end{bmatrix}'
>  = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}. $$ where $a,b,c,d$ are real constants and
>   $ad-bc=0.$

**Question**. Discuss all possible behaviors of the solutions and sketch the corresponding phase portraits

This is exactly how the question being asked. First and foremost is the determinant being zero is a "typo" ? Because if the determinant is zero, and the origin being not an isolated critical point, there will be infinitely many solutions.

If it's a typo and determinant is not zero, what's the most efficient and shorter way of classifying the zero solution. I can just go ahead and calculate the eigen values and argue for (stable/unstable)nodes, saddle-points, spiral points and centre. It'll be too long I presume. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Determinant being zero means one or both of the eigenvalues are zero. It doesn't imply any specific things about the stability

Comment: OK. then since there are infinitely many solutions, how should I answer the question. I think I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a linear system with two states, $x=\pmatrix{x_1&x_2}^T$ in general form:
$$\dot{x}=Ax$$
the general form of the solution is:
$$x(t)=\Phi(t)x(0)$$
where $\Phi(t)=e^{At}$ can be evaluated by converting $A$ to its Jordan canonical form.
$$A=M^{-1}J M\implies e^{At}=M^{-1}e^{Jt}M$$
This means the general solution of the system is a linear combination of the elements of $e^{Jt}$. Now in your case where $\det A=0$, we can be sure that one of the eigenvalues are zero. Thus
$$\begin{align}
J&=\pmatrix{\lambda_1&0\\0&0}\text{ or}&\pmatrix{0&0\\0&0}&\text{ or }\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}\\
e^{Jt}&=\pmatrix{e^{\lambda_1 t}&0\\0&1}\text{or}&\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}&\text{ or }\pmatrix{1&t\\0&1}
\end{align}$$
If $e^{Jt}$ is not a function of $t$ (meaning $J=0$), then the system is *static*. If $\lambda_1\neq 0$ you can analyze the system's behavior based on the real part of $\lambda_1$, i.e. one of the system's **modes** is:

- unstable if $\Re(\lambda_1)>0$
- stable and vanishing if $\Re(\lambda_1)<0$
- oscillating if $\Re(\lambda_1)=0$

Comment: Thank you very much. Quick question, when you find the matrix $e^{Jt},$ I understand how you got the first and the second one. Can you explain how you got the third one ?

Comment: @Fib1123 I assume you are familiar with the Taylor expansion. For a square matrix $j$, we have
$$e^{Jt}=I+Jt+\frac{1}{2!}J^2 t^2+...$$
and observe that $J^2=0$

Comment: @Fib1123 I just didn't notice that you have already mentioned the matrix is real. In this case, if an eigenvalue is complex then it must have a conjugate. Which means $\lambda_1$ cannot have an imaginary part and it is definitely real. So the system cannot be oscillatory

Comment: Right. So there are no spiral or centre orbits.